# jQuery-HTML: Display Two multiple feeds into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, feed

So, I was trying to merge two feeds, and display it in two columns sorting by time, starting as the newest from the top left corner, and the oldest at the bottom right corner. To be precise, this is the order that I want:

```
------------------------
Newest     | 4th Newest
2nd Newest | 5th Newest
3rd Newest | 6th Newest 
------------------------
```

The problem is, the following code did not work, and returned an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: item is not a function  (index:329)
```

The code I used is below.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var blogFeed = $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://www.foxinflame.tk/blog/feed",
      dataType: "xml"
    })
    var videoFeed = $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/videoFeed.php",
      dataType: "xml"
    })
    $.when(blogFeed, videoFeed).done(function(blogXML, videoXML){
//The one below this one is the 329 line
      var combinedXML = $(blogXML).find("item").concat(videoXML.find("entry"));
      var sortedXML = combinedXML.sort(function(videoFeedCompare, blogFeedCompare){
        var videoFeedDate = Date.parse(videoFeedCompare.find("published"));
        var blogFeedDate = Date.parse(blogFeedCompare.find("pubDate"));
        return videoFeedDate - blogFeedDate;
      });
      console.log(sortedXML.item(0));
      sortedXML.forEach(function(eachCounter) {
        console.log("stuff");
        var title = $(this).find("title").text();
        console.log(title);
        var description = $(this).find("description").text();
        var comments = +($(this).find("slash:comments").text());
        var pubDate = $(this).find("pubDate").text();
        var link = $(this).find("link").text();
        if(eachCounter < 3){
                  $("#firstColumnOfItems").append("<div class='postCollection'><div class='z-depth-1 blogpost' style='min-height: 300px'><br><h5><a style='color:black' href='"+link+"'>"+title+"</a></h5><br><p>"+description+"<br><i>"+comments+" Comments. Published at "+pubDate+"</i></p></div></div>");
                } else if(eachCounter < 6) {
                  $("#secondColumnOfItems").append("<div class='postCollection'><div class='z-depth-1 blogpost' style='min-height: 300px'><br><h5><a style='color:black' href='"+link+"'>"+title+"</a></h5><p>"+description+"<br><i>"+comments+" Comments. Published at "+pubDate+"</i></p></div></div>");
                }
      });
    });
  })
</script>
```

Do note, that VideoFeed.php just does `file_get_contents` and echos it, because JS couldn't do it (no access control allow origin header is present).

What is wrong, and How would I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `console.log(sortedXML.item(0));` to `console.log(sortedXML.item[0]);`

Comment: Now It returns "Entry is not a function." at the line with the ``Concat()`` function. It also doesn't echo the item to the console, yet.

Comment: You must see if `$(blogXML).find("item")` is returing something or not. Anyway, I think that `.concat`don't work for jquery element array. Maybe you could try something else, like `.push`

Comment: It looks like ``combinedXML`` is not an Array. The Foreach function does not work on it, and it does not return true when checked with ``combinedXML === Array``. Yes, I did use Push.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and maybe I can help you. Only looking at the code is hard to tell

Comment: That, is true. But, since my code uses feeds from other website, the "No Access Control Allow Origin Header" blocks the code from working on JSFiddle.